# i am making a ball rolling game and i added jumping but for some reason i can jump infinite times

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i am making a ball rolling game and i added jumping the the game but for some reason i can jump infinite times here is my code (i put the jump script with the movement script)

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ballcontroll : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float speed;

    private Rigidbody rb;

    

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float jump;
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
            jump = 14.0f;
        else
            jump = 0;
        Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (moveVertical, jump , moveHorizontal);

        rb.AddForce(movement * speed);
    
    }

}
```

Comment: The reason you can jump in the air is that there isn't anything written in your code to prevent the player from jumping repeatedly. You have to add a check whether the player can jump before allowing the player to jump.

Comment: what do you think i should add to my code to my code to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can jump infinitely because you are not checking if the ball is on the ground. There are several ways to solve this problem. I would recommend you to watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ptvK4Fp5vRY&ab_channel=CodeMonkey) video.

You could also watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c3iEl5AwUF8&ab_channel=CodeMonkey) if you want to know about alternative ways of checking for ground.

Comment: Awesome! I'd appreciate it if you'd mark this as an answer.